# How to decide between HttpURLConnection and JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, httpurlconnection

I came across two ways of consuming a web-service.

1. `HttpURLConnection`.
2. `javax.xml.ws.Service` in JAX-WS

How can I choose between these two ways of consuming?

Is there any performance difference between these two ways of consuming a web service?

Comment: JAX-WS is built on top of `HttpURLConnection`. You use the former if you need what it does. You use the latter if you need to work at a lower level. They are not in competition.